# SystemD SysV generator and mounts

Tags: systemd

So `systemd-sysv-generator` converts old style init.d files into systemd service files. But it might do this before all mounts have been mounted.

I have some legacy commercial software that lives in /opt which is a separate mount point. It creates a symlink from /etc/init.d/their_service to a file in /opt

So when the server boots, `systemd-sysv-generator` cant yet read the linked file and fails to create a service and thus fails to start the service.

As the legacy software is managed by another team and they have the power to update it themselves, I don't want to start copying the file out of /opt and replacing the symlink. Or worse, try rewriting this into a systemd service myself.

Is there any way to have `systemd-sysv-generator` fire after `opt.mount`?

Comment: exactly the same issue here and I don't find any way to make systemd mount local fs earlier or to run systemd-sysv-generator after all local are fs are mounted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from [iwaseatenbyagrue](https://serverfault.com/users/402709/iwaseatenbyagrue) to read https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html I found this section

> **initrd-fs.target**
>
> systemd-fstab-generator(3) automatically adds dependencies of type Before= to sysroot-usr.mount and all mount points found in /etc/fstab that have x-initrd.mount and not have noauto mount options set.

So my fix was to do the following

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` to have the x-initrd.mount option for my /opt mount point

> /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt /opt ext4 nodev,**x-initrd.mount** 0 0

2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` to list the extra mount point in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rootvg/root rd.lvm.lv=rootvg/swap rd.lvm.lv=rootvg/usr **rd.lvm.lv=rootvg/opt** ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet"

3. Rebuild the boot

> grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.conf
>
> dracut -f

These steps combined cause SystemD to correctly mount /opt early in the boot and succeed with `systemd-sysv-generator`

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to create a drop-in for their service, that specifies dependencies/order.

For example:

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/their_service.service.d
$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/their_service.service.d/50-require_mounts.conf
[Unit]
Wants=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target
```

However, the SysV script could be adapted to sort this problem (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html):

> **remote-fs.target**
>   Similar to local-fs.target, but for remote mount points.
>
> systemd automatically adds dependencies of type After= for this target unit to all SysV init script service units with an LSB header referring to the "$remote_fs" facility.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I don't want to try editing their SysV script. A drop in might work though. The /opt mount is local (in the same VG as /) just a separate mount point.

A drop in file with a Wants=opt.mount might work though.